# Load internal div after clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an invisible div by `display: none`.

I need to load div after clicking on button, not OnPageLoad.

Notice :

I said **LOAD** div after **Clicking** button, i'm not talking about **SHOW** div.

I don't want load div on page load.

HTML is here :

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Load Div" />
<div class="content" style="display: none;">
    <img src="http://www.kippaxvet.com.au/Portals/kippaxvet/cute%20pup.jpg" />
</div>
```

How can i do that ?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT** {More information} :

I have a div with many elements and images in there.

If i load that div onPageLoad it's very heavy and take long times.

I just need to **Load** that div when the user want show it up.

Comment: You can look into creating a div with JavaScript and adding that to the DOM. `document.createElement('div')`

Comment: @RickHoving What about `img` and all contents inside div ?

Comment: I don't see in what use case you would want to append an element rather than just showing it. Can you explain a little why you chose to approach the problem using this method?

Comment: Perhaps this link will help you out: https://coderwall.com/p/evmqoa

Comment: @Sam First post has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Load Div" onclick="load()"/>

function load()
{
  var imgDiv = document.createElement('div');
  $(imgDiv ).addClass('content');
  $(imgDiv).append('<img id="dynamicImg" src="http://www.kippaxvet.com.au/Portals/kippaxvet/cute%20pup.jpg" />')
  // add the imgDiv to your parent container element. 
  // for e.g. $("#container").append(imgDiv)
}
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vendettamit/QB8Hv/